# fixing sql data EG 000-575.33

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was given a few thousand records of varchars such as the one above. They all need to be 10 characters, and I guess they just indiscriminately padded zeros on them. How can I move the negative sign over to the left so `000-575.33` becomes `-000575.33`?

Comment: If it's a number, why not store it as a numerical datatype?  Also, what DBMS is this for?

Comment: Is the `-` always the fourth character, or is it in different places in different records?

Comment: `'-'||replace(the_column, '-', '')`

Comment: microsoft sql server, varchars, the negative sign can be anywhere or not present at all (as in some are perfectly good).

Comment: Do they all need to have a `-` prefix?  Or do the ones without a `-` not need one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do. If they aren't already padded correctly let us know and we can stuff those.

```
declare @v varchar(64) = '000-575.33'
select 
    case 
        when CHARINDEX('-',@v) > 1 then '-' + replace(@v,'-','')
        else @v
    end
```